# aptsources.distro.NoDistroTemplateException: Error: could not find a distribution template for Elementary/next

Tags: ppa, elementary, add-apt-repository, pantheon

The following happens every time I want to add a repository - It is not working since I have installed (and then uninstalled) pantheon desktop :(

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:appgrid/stable
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository", line 107, in <module>
    sp = SoftwareProperties(options=options)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py", line 118, in __init__
    self.reload_sourceslist()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py", line 613, in reload_sourceslist
    self.distro.get_sources(self.sourceslist)    
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aptsources/distro.py", line 91, in get_sources
    raise NoDistroTemplateException(
aptsources.distro.NoDistroTemplateException: Error: could not find a distribution template for Elementary/next
```

Answer (score 3):

Uninstalling the `pantheon-desktop` package is not enough, because it also installs dependencies that will stay. You have to clean up the sytem.

Install `ppa-purge`:

```
sudo apt install ppa-purge
```

Then remove the Elementary PPA [with that tool](https://askubuntu.com/questions/307/how-can-ppas-be-removed):

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa:elementary-os/stable
```

or whatever ppa you used, e.g. daily --> `ppa:elementary-os/daily`

([via](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2394850))

Comment: I have the same problem, and purging didn't help. Ubuntu seems to be back to normal, but os version is Elementary/next